# pyparsing: setResultsName for multiple elements get combined

Tags: python, pyparsing

Here is the text I'm parsing:

```
x ~ normal(mu, 1)
y ~ normal(mu2, 1)
```

The parser matches those lines using:

```
model_definition = Group(identifier.setResultsName('random_variable_name') + '~' + expression).setResultsName('model_definition')

// end of line: .setResultsName('model_definition')
```

The problem is that when there are two model definitions, they aren't named separately in the ParseResults object:

[image]

It looks like the first one gets overridden by the second. The reason I'm naming them is to make executing the lines easier - this way I (hopefully) don't have to figure out what is going on at evaluation time - the parser has already labelled everything. How can I get both `model_definition`s labelled? It would be nice if `model_definition` held a list of every model definition found.

Just in case, here is some more of my code:

```
model_definition = Group(identifier.setResultsName('random_variable_name') + '~' + expression).setResultsName('model_definition')
expression << Or([function_application, number, identifier, list_literal, probability_expression])
statement = Optional(newline) + Or([model_definition, assignment, function_application]) + Optional(newline)
line = OneOrMore('\n').suppress()
comment = Group('#' + SkipTo(newline)).suppress()
program = OneOrMore(Or([line, statement, comment]))
ast = program.parseString(input_string)
return ast
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not documented that I know of, but I found something in `pyparsing.py`:[image]

I changed `.setResultsName('model_definition')` to `.setResultsName('model_definition*')` and they listed correctly!

[image]

Edit: it is documented, but it is a flag you pass to `setResultsName`:

> setResultsName( string, **listAllMatches=False** ) - name to be given to tokens matching the element; if multiple tokens within a repetition group (such as ZeroOrMore or delimitedList) the default is to return only the last matching token - **if listAllMatches is set to True, then a list of matching tokens is returned**.

Comment: Still have an issue though - if you return multiple, it fails to split out each child. :/

Comment: yes ! thank you, I was having a similar issue and it fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Here is enough of your code to get things to work:

```
from pyparsing import *

# fake in the bare minimum to parse the given test strings
identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums)
integer = Word(nums)
function_call = identifier + '(' + Optional(delimitedList(identifier | integer)) + ')'
expression = function_call

model_definition = Group(identifier.setResultsName('random_variable_name') + '~' + expression)

sample = """
x ~ normal(mu, 1)
y ~ normal(mu2, 1)
"""
```

The trailing `'*'` is there in `setResultsName` for those cases where you use the short form of `setResultsName`:  `expr("name*")` vs `expr.setResultsName("name", listAllMatches=True)`. If you prefer calling `setResultsName`, then I would not use the `'*'` notation, but would pass the `listAllMatches` argument.

If you are getting names that step on each other, you may need to add a level of Grouping.  Here is your solution using `listAllMatches=True`, by virtue of the trailing `'*'` notation:

```
model_definition1 = model_definition('model_definition*')
print OneOrMore(model_definition1).parseString(sample).dump()
```

It returns this parse result:

```
[['x', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu', '1', ')'], ['y', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu2', '1', ')']]
- model_definition: [['x', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu', '1', ')'], ['y', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu2', '1', ')']]
  [0]:
    ['x', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu', '1', ')']
    - random_variable_name: x
  [1]:
    ['y', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu2', '1', ')']
```

Here is a variation that does not use `listAllMatches`, but adds another level of Group:

```
model_definition2 = model_definition('model_definition')
print OneOrMore(Group(model_definition2)).parseString(sample).dump()
```

gives:

```
[[['x', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu', '1', ')']], [['y', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu2', '1', ')']]]
[0]:
  [['x', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu', '1', ')']]
  - model_definition: ['x', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu', '1', ')']
    - random_variable_name: x
[1]:
  [['y', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu2', '1', ')']]
  - model_definition: ['y', '~', 'normal', '(', 'mu2', '1', ')']
    - random_variable_name: y
```

In both cases, I see the full content being returned, so I don't quit understand what you mean by "if you return multiple, it fails to split out each child."

Comment: Thanks Paul. I meant that it doesn't continue to give the names for children of `model_definition`s. I ended up using `setParseAction` and returning (name, tokens). I'll need to use `setParseAction` eventually, anyway, I think.